# Gmail API - gapi not defined node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, gmail-api

I am using the below function from Google Gmail APIs to get all the messages from an user and I got gapi not defined error when I executed the code.

```
 /**
     * Retrieve Messages in user's mailbox matching query.
     *
     * @param  {String} userId User's email address. The special value 'me'
     * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
     * @param  {String} query String used to filter the Messages listed.
     * @param  {Function} callback Function to call when the request is complete.
     */
    function listMessages(userId, query, callback) {
      var getPageOfMessages = function(request, result) {
        request.execute(function(resp) {
          result = result.concat(resp.messages);
          var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
          if (nextPageToken) {
            request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
              'userId': userId,
              'pageToken': nextPageToken,
              'q': query
            });
            getPageOfMessages(request, result);
          } else {
            callback(result);
          }
        });
      };
      var initialRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
        'userId': userId,
        'q': query
      });
      getPageOfMessages(initialRequest, []);
    }
```

I have below libraries defined in my code

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
var readline = require('readline'); 
var google = require('googleapis');
```

Error that I got :

```
var initialRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
                       ^
ReferenceError: gapi is not defined
```

Any help where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Google has a nice quickstart for the Gmail API on node, see:  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs

You install the Google API library (if you haven't already) with:

```
npm install googleapis@27 --save
```

You need to go through the Oauth2 flow to get authorization to access the API, but since you're working on the server side (e.g. node), the flow is going to be much different than many of the client-side (e.g. browser) Javascript examples out there.

See the file linked in the quickstart for a full example:  https://github.com/gsuitedevs/node-samples/blob/master/gmail/quickstart/index.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this script during runtime so that gapi gets loaded.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is a good npm module in case you want to use it which will handle all by itself.